# Labels are floating up and down when resolution changes

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, css, chartist.js

I am using bar charts from Chartist.js in my web application. These bar charts have names as labels.

Some names are very large and overlapping on each other. So, using JavaScript I swapped these names with their shorter version (i.e. if the length of name is bigger then 10 characters then change rest of characters with three dots '...').

I also wanted to rotate these labels to -15 Deg. I use  following CSS property to rotate them

```
    transform: rotate(-15deg) translate(5px,10px);
```

Issue: Above property have rotated them successfully for only one resolution.
When I checked same bar chart of other resolution, they get displaced from their location and float above for larger resolution. When I remove this property they stays fine at their respective location and also behave fine for all resolution.

Rotation is causing then to float. Giving them transform origin is also not helping. DOM for these labels is as follows and below two are the images of issue.

DOM

```
<g class="ct-labels">
<foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="40" y="195" width="131.43892045454547" height="70">
<span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 131px; height: 70px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" data-assignedtoname="ARORA,VIKAS">VIKAS, ARORA</span>
</foreignObject>
```

img1: [Normal Desktop Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD1eB.png)

img2: [Smaller Desktop Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Wyp.png)

Comment: Is there any one who can answer?